# Creating a post by sending HTTP request to Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I want to post on my  facebook page by sending a HTTP POST. The way I am doing this is by creating a permanent access_token that is used to post to my facebook page. The problem is the access_token can be easily taken/inspected using firebug or any other tool (since it is hard-coded). How can I send it in a way that is kept from others.

```
$appID = 'MY_APP_ID';
$fb_page_id = 'MY_PAGE_ID';
$fb_page_access_token = 'PERMANENT_ACCESS_TOKEN';

$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'
      . '<html><body>'
      . '<div id="fb-root"></div>'
      . "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
           function post_to_fb(commentText, commentUsername, commentLink) {
            var logoName = get_logoname_from_link(commentLink);
            var strURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/" . $fb_page_id . "/feed';
            var params = 'link=' + commentLink + '&name=Brandchamp+-+' + logoName + '&message=[' + commentUsername +'+commented on ' + logoName + ':]+' + commentText + '&access_token=" . $fb_page_access_token . "';

            var xmlHttpReq;
            xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
            xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlHttpReq.send(params);
           }

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
               FB.init({
                 appId: " . $appID . ",
                 status: true,
                 cookie: true,
                 xfbml: true,
               });

              FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
                var commentQuery = FB.Data.query('SELECT fromid, text FROM comment WHERE post_fbid=\'' + response.commentID + '\' AND object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url=\'' + response.href + '\')');
                var userQuery = FB.Data.query('SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid in (select fromid from {0})', commentQuery);

                FB.Data.waitOn([commentQuery, userQuery], function () {
                  var commentRow = commentQuery.value[0];
                  var userRow = userQuery.value[0];

                  var commentText = commentRow.text;
                  var commentUsername = userRow.name;

                  post_to_fb(commentText, commentUsername, response.href);
                });

             });


           };
           (function() {
             var e = document.createElement('script');
             e.async = true;
             e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
             document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
           }());
        </script>"
      . '</body></html>';
print $html;
```

Comment: Sniffing POST data passed over HTTPS not something easily achieved, you should be more worried about existence of `access_token` as plain text in your page if it's served over HTTP than about sniffing form submission to graph.

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't let users see your access token: you have to create some kind of proxy which will post to your's page wall server-side

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem if a user who is granting you permission can see his/her own access_token in firebug. Firebug is on client side only. Also, official javascript sdk gives access_token to client. I dont think its bad.

User can always see his/her own password :) . What is bad in it ?

You should care about sniffing access_token over network. As @Juicy suggested use https to overcome that situation.

**Edit after reading comment:**

In your situation, I would suggest not to use javascript/ajax.

Also, I would recommend to use an sdk over your own php code.
An sdk uses all security measures which should be taken.

Official php sdk:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: the access_token above doesn't belong to the user. It is a permanent access_token that is used to give anyone who uses it the ability to post on that facebook page, simply by sending an http post request that has this access_token as a parameter.